# Find a physical quantity equal to $1/\sqrt\pi$

Tags: pi

What physical quantity gives a good sense of $1/\sqrt{\pi}$?

An example of a "physical quantity that gives a good sense" of $\pi$ would be the area of a disk with unit radius.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The radius of a disk with unit area.